# How to retrieve form-data values in Express js?

Tags: express, postman

I created a form data in Postman and send a http post request. but when I send the request, it shows there is no form data in the destination!

here is my codes in backend :

`app.js` file:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
var routesImagesApi = require('./api/routes/imagesrouters');
app.use('/api/images', routesImagesApi);
```

`api/routes/imagesrouters.js` file:

```
var router = express.Router();
var ctrlAuth = require('../controllers/images');
router.post('/imageUpload', ctrlAuth.imageUpload);
```

`controllers/images.js` file:

```
module.exports.imageUpload = function (req, res) {
    res.status(200);    
    res.json({"Returned data":req.body});
}
```

I created a request in `postman` with two key-value form-data body.

here is my request:

```
POST > http://localhost:3000/api/images/imageUpload
```

and form-data body key-values are these :

```
key:name , value:Sarah
key:family , value:Thomas
```

Below image is `Postman` screenshot :

[image: postman screenshot]

I expected postman show me the form-data key values but as you can see it shows nothing!

```
{
    "Returned data": {}
}
```

Do you have any idea?

Comment: You need to use a body parser that support formdata which the `body-parser` module does not support. Check out other body parser modules such as `multer` or `formidable` or `multiparty`

Comment: can `multer` retrieve string type form data? @slebetman

Comment: Yes is too short for a comment so I'm typing extra words to allow me to post this

Comment: I would thank you for doing this. @slebetman

Answer (score 0):

Please use the multer package  or you could write a custom handler for making express handle multi part form data i.e "files/imgs..etc "
[multer package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer)
and
[writing your own custom handler](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/HTTP/servers/how-to-handle-multipart-form-data/)

p.s this could be a duplicate issue